# simple javascript dropdown that loads specific urls (not domain names)

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm currently using this code to try and setup a simple dropdown that when you select an option in the dropdown, it autoloads a url.  (not just a website).  here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleSelect(elm)
    {
    window.location = elm.value+"";
    }
    </script>

    <div class="menu1" align="left">
        <select name="formal" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/">Home</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/map.php">Lake Information</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/mls.php" class="smalllink">Custom Search</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/let_us_find_it.php" class="smalllink">Let Us Find It</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/Map.pdf" class="smalllink">Lake Map</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/contact.php" class="smalllink">Contact Us</a></option>
    <option value="http://richlandchambers.net/lakeprop101.php/" class="smalllink">Lake Property 101</a></option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Currently all it's doing is loading the root domain name.  ie. when I select "lake Information" in the dropdown, it's still only loading http://richlandchambers.net  not http://richlandchambers.net/map.php

I've tried several javascript methods and they all just load the domain name not the specific url.  What is required to get these dropdowns to auto load a website internal page?

here's the menu in action:
http://www.richlandchambersrealty.idxco.com/idx/4472/userLogin.php
(you have to minimize your browser to allow the bootrstrap to respond to show the drop down menu at top)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a problem with your code, when clicking on the link to `http://richlandchambers.net/map.php` in your question, I get redirected to the homepage as well.

Comment: oh ok.  Thanks.  I think i need to add www. in front of it or else it reverts to homepage.